# Calling PyPy sandbox from another language

Tags: python, haskell, sandbox, ffi, pypy

I'll preface this by saying I am quite new to PyPy, though fairly experienced with Python.

I'm looking to run a web app where I run untrusted Python code. The PyPy sandboxing features look ideal for what I'm doing.

The [PyPy docs on sandboxing](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html) indicate that you can call a PyPy sandbox from either Python or PyPy. This seems to imply that there's some separate program or executable that is the sandbox.

I'm wondering, is it possible to call a PyPy sandbox from a non-Python language? I'm looking at Haskell in particular, but it's also very possible that I could use C or C++ as an intermediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  The PyPy sandbox is a separate process communicating only via stdin/stdout.  If you want to rewrite the "external" part, you can; it's not using anything that should be too heavily Python-related.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of how to do this in some language? Is `pypy-c-sandbox` just an executable?

Comment: Yes, pypy-c-sandbox is just an executable.  The example of how to do that is https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/raw/default/pypy/sandbox/pypy_interact.py and the sandlib and vfs modules it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sandboxing feature of PyPy is not being maintained any more, see http://www.pypy.org/features.html#sandboxing